# Не работает простейший код паскаль

Tags: pascal

```
program Bablische;
uses Crt;
var x, a : longint;
begin
     x:=1;
     repeat 
     a=3200000+231435*x-380000*x;
     x=x+1;
     until a<=0;
     write (x);
     readln
end.
```

Нужно узнать количество операций, за которые a будет равно нулю или меньше)
Выдает ошибку

```
source.pas(7,33) Error: Illegal expression
source.pas(7,6) Warning: Variable "a" does not seem to be initialized
source.pas(8,11) Error: Illegal expression
source.pas(13) Fatal: There were 2 errors compiling module, stopping
Error: /usr/bin/ppcx64 returned an error exitcode
```

Со школы в паскаль не смотрела, не могу понять что не так

Comment: source.pas(8,11) Error: Illegal expression пропущено `:=`

Comment: там еще и дальше пропущено. там еще бы х за скобки вынести в выражении

Comment: @andreymal, то, что он считает, что именно в этом месте её инициализирует. К тому же, это предупреждение.

Answer (score 5):

> ```
> a=3200000+231435*x-380000*x;
> x=x+1;
> ```

В этих строках должно быть `:=` вместо `=`.

> ```
> uses Crt;
> ```

А эту лучше вообще выкинуть.

---

Вот тебе 23: https://ideone.com/PDvB7A

Comment: от души душевно :3

Comment: @Лириум, если решение помогло, то стоит принять ответ нажатием на галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы посчитать в вашем случае когда a<=0 - нужно воспользоваться следующими кодом в нужном месте:

```
var k:integer;
begin
k:=0;
if a<=0 then k:=k+1;
writeln('a<=0', k 'раз');
end.
```